# sqlite3 sql query functions in specific folder not working when used in other folders of my express API project

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

SQLite Queries in one folder, which has links to the dataBase. When importing these Functions to locations to use they are trying to apply them to db in the current repository which the function is being run.

I have previously stated where the db is using in the file with the Queries, however, this route is not seeming to be used.

In the first folder i have a file which is trying to run the imported SQL query function...
In a folder inside the above folder I have a file (sql.js) where i am exporting the SQL query functions, and the Database.sqlite is in this folder.

```js
// this is my exported function with route to data.sqlite
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.sqlite');

const getData = (data) => {
    db.all(`SELECT title, desc, details FROM "${data}"`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(rows);
        }
    });
}




// this is the file importing and trying to run that function:
getData('foo');



/* 
The error code:
[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: foo] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}



It also creates a new table in the same directory as the importing file
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out what was wrong, the route to the database is from the root directory, not from the current directory that the function is in!

HOPE this helps anyone having a similar issue. :)